# How to get if children exists

Tags: php, sql, symfony, doctrine

I have two Entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="main")
 */
class Main
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Sub", mappedBy="mains")
     * @ORM\OrderBy({"position" = "ASC"})
     */
    protected $subs;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    protected $name;
}

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="sub")
 */
class Sub
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
    * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection
    *
    * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Main", inversedBy="subs")
    * @ORM\JoinTable(name="sub_main",
    *   joinColumns={
    *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="sub_id", referencedColumnName="id")
    *   },
    *   inverseJoinColumns={
    *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="main_id", referencedColumnName="id")
    *   }
    * )
    */
    protected $mains; 

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    protected $name;
}
```

It works good. In controller I would like to get all Mains objects which have childrens (Sub).

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$queryBuilder = $em->createQueryBuilder();

$qb->select('m, s')
            ->from('AppBundle:Main', 'm')
            ->where('ONLY MAINS WITH CHILDRENS (SUB)')
            ->leftJoin('m.subs', 's')
                ;

        $mains = $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
```

So what condition should be in where clause?

I found that in simply SQL I can use subqueries or operator exists, but how can I use it in Doctrine in Symfony 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `->where('m.subs IS NOT EMPTY');`